# What is the music at the end credits of Better Call Saul?

Tags: soundtrack, better-call-saul

One of the features that made Breaking Bad such a great series was its clever use of music to enhance the tone and atmosphere of many scenes. Some of the soundtrack used existing music for great effect (one of the things that sold me on the first episode was the frantic money cleaning scene towards the end of episode 1 set to "Out Of Time Man") and some was new.

It looks like the prequel will keep the same standard. But some of the well-chosen music isn't easy to identify. Hence the following question.

The new, and so far excellent, Breaking Bad prequel [Better Call Saul](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3032476/?ref_=nv_sr_1) has an unidentifiable piece of music over the end credits that sets some of the tone for the series. What is it? And was it made specially for the show or is it from an existing album?

Since the IMDB listing for the series doesn't yet include any soundtrack listing, I'm hoping to community can help.

Comment: As this question asks to identify a piece of music (which just so happens to be used) in a TV show, and not about the show itself, it is edging towards being off-topic. Was there a reason you wished to identify this particular piece (i.e. it was jarringly inappropriate, or conversely fit the mood well)? It would be appreciated if you would tie your desire for the music information to its use in the episode.

Comment: @CGCampbell One of the distinguishing features of breaking Bad was its excellent choice of music to supplement the dramatic point of some scenes. Better call Saul seems to be trying the same. So I think this is a relevant question here. Besides, when was knowing what music appears *less* relevant to the show than, say, knowing which actors appear?

Answer (score 3):

Guess this is what you were looking for:

[Shook Milestone](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3gM8_SL9BP0)

But it is not quite the same as the ending music, according to this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LMd-_1nQc_M&spfreload=10), which says it might be created by UK band "Little Barrie", and the song track is not released yet.

Comment: While this is another interesting piece from the soundtrack it isn't the one from the end-credits. Nice to know what it is though.